# Glazedlists: get result after action performed in FilterList

Tags: java, filter, action, glazedlists

I have a jtable that I can filter with TextComponentMatcherEditor of Glazedlists... And I have a textField that show the number of rows of this table...
How I can get the number of rows when the filter as been applyed?
Every key inserted on filter, the textFiled must be updated...

I hope my query was clear, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you have a `FilterList` somewhere whose job is it to handle the filtering between the source event list and the matcher editor. In which case `FilterList.size()` is all you need to call to get at the number of items present.

Of course, reacting to when the list has changed is the fundamental step. Because GlazedLists is all about "events" on lists you won't be surprised that there are simple ways of listening in to when changes occur, `EventList.addListEventListener()` being an obvious example.

I've written a small sample program of a JTable hooked up the GlazedLists way and reacting to a text field filter. At the bottom of the GUI is a JLabel that displays the number of items currently displayed.

NB I've only tested again GlazedLists v1.8 but I should think it's fine back to v1.5.

```
import ca.odell.glazedlists.BasicEventList;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.EventList;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.FilterList;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.GlazedLists;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.SortedList;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.TextFilterator;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.event.ListEvent;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.event.ListEventListener;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.gui.TableFormat;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.matchers.ThreadedMatcherEditor;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.swing.EventTableModel;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.swing.TextComponentMatcherEditor;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TextFilterCount {


    private EventList<Person> eventList = new BasicEventList<Person>();

    public TextFilterCount() {
        setupGui();
        populateTable();
    }

    private void populateTable() {
        eventList.add(new Person("Charles", "Dickens"));
        eventList.add(new Person("George", "Orwell"));
        eventList.add(new Person("John", "Steinbeck"));
        eventList.add(new Person("Jospeh", "Heller"));
    }

    private void setupGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GlazedListed TextFilter count example");

        final JLabel countLabel = new JLabel();

        frame.setSize(600, 400);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTextField textField = new JTextField();

        SortedList sortedList = new SortedList(eventList);

        TextFilterator<Person> personFilterator = new TextFilterator<Person>() {
            @Override
            public void getFilterStrings(List baseList, Person person) {
                baseList.add(person.getFirstName());
                baseList.add(person.getLastName());
            }
        };

        TextComponentMatcherEditor matcherEditor = new TextComponentMatcherEditor(textField, personFilterator);
        final FilterList filteredList = new FilterList(sortedList, new ThreadedMatcherEditor(matcherEditor));

        filteredList.addListEventListener(new ListEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void listChanged(ListEvent le) {
                System.out.println("List changed.");
                countLabel.setText("" + filteredList.size());
            }
        });

        String[] propertyNames = new String[] {"firstName", "lastName"};
        String[] columnLabels = new String[] {"First name", "Last name"};

        TableFormat tf = GlazedLists.tableFormat(Person.class, propertyNames, columnLabels);
        JTable table = new JTable(new EventTableModel(filteredList, tf));

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        mainPanel.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        mainPanel.add(countLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
        private String firstName = "";
        private String lastName = "";

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Person p) {
            if (this.getLastName().equals(p.getLastName())) {
                return this.getFirstName().compareTo(p.getFirstName());
            }

            return this.getLastName().compareTo(p.getLastName());
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TextFilterCount();
    }
}
```